# What are some potential reasons for a PHP script terminating unexpectedly by php-fpm which trigger the 504 gateway timeout?

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

What are some potential reasons for intermittent PHP script termination, particularly observed after periods of inactivity or when attempting to log in through a new browser instance? The issue resolves after canceling the login request and trying again. Additionally, how can the following error log entry from php7.4-fpm.log be interpreted?

php7.4-fpm.log

```
[24-Mar-2024 05:49:47] WARNING: [pool domain] child 2889619, script '/home/domain/public_html/wp-login.php' (request: "POST /wp-login.php") execution timed out (218.590861 sec), terminating
[24-Mar-2024 05:49:47] WARNING: [pool domain] child 2889619 exited on signal 15 (SIGTERM) after 31074.802894 seconds from start
```

Comment: The script takes too long to execute. Debug the script.

Comment: **Question:**
What could be causing intermittent login issues with a standard `wp-login.php` script from the WordPress package? The problem manifests after prolonged periods of inactivity, prompting users to log in again, or when attempting to access the login page through a new browser instance. Cancelling the initial login request and resubmitting the form resolves the issue. Could this behavior be linked to session management, and if so, how might sessions be implicated as the root cause?

Comment: If the `wp-login.php` runs for 31000 seconds (over 8 hours!) your environment is *severely* broken, or your wordpress installation is compromised and is running malware. I would expect `wp-login.php` to *never* exceed five seconds.

Comment: @vidarlo 31000 seconds passed since the start of the php-fpm instance, not an individual script. The script timed out after 218 seconds which is still not healthy.

Comment: @AlexD Ah! Thanks for pointing out my mistake :) Still, 218 seconds indicates severe problems; perhaps a timeout when connecting to database or similar.

Comment: I just enabled WP_DEBUG_LOG, i couldn't find any error or warning from wordpress.  Also its a custom wordpress theme, and it works fine on local machine. Issue exist only in live server. Any idea how to debug the issue?

Comment: Increase nginx gateway timeout to 500s (for example). Then check, if something (!) is coming back or if it is just terminating.